# Add lib to SDK generated from meta-toolchain-qt5 with Yocto

Tags: sdk, qt5, yocto

I'm building an core-image-minimal for my target with Yocto.

To build an application for it, I generate an SDK using:

`bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5`

It works fine, but the SDK do not include all the lib installed on my target.

So, I tried the following:

```
bitbake core-image-minimal -c populate_sdk
```

It generate an SDK, but when installed, it does not include all the files present in the SDK generated by meta-toolchain-qt5

In sysroots/cortex...gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5 there is no directory mkspecs.

So I would like to generate the SDK using meta-toolchain-sdk, with a meta-toolchain-sdk.bbappend file to add the lib that I need. How can I do that?

I want to include log4cxx and tried the following:

```
SDKIMAGE_FEATURES += "liblog4cxx10"
```

Could not find log4cxx files in the SDK :-(

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: I'm have few question about using this SDK target: 1. I'm couldn't find this recipe (meta-toolchain-qt5) in poky and in others meta-qt5 layers - please provide info about it. 2. Are You sure that created bbappend file for _meta-toolchain-sdk.bb_ are correctly used (resolved/applied by bitbake) - You can check it by checking by generate logs for this target -> $ bitbake -e meta-toolchain-qt &> log1 ; $ cat log1 | grep SDKIMAGE_FEATURES . My assumptions are that You append file are wasn't used properly, also You can delete all tmp/ sscache/ and cache dir's for clean build. Please provide update.

Comment: Sorry for my oversight - [meta-toolchain-qt5 recipe link](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5/blob/master/recipes-qt/meta/meta-toolchain-qt5.bb).

Comment: Hello. Here are the results of the cmd you provided: `# $SDKIMAGE_FEATURES [3 operations]
SDKIMAGE_FEATURES=" liblog4cxx10"
#     "${@complementary_globs("SDKIMAGE_FEATURES", d)}"`

Comment: I would prefer not removing the /tmp directory. Building sdk from scratch is very long... :-(

Comment: Ok, I' think I find solution - try to use this recipe in Your append file as _nativesdk_ (it should look like -> _nativesdk-liblog4cxx1_) [docs](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-nativesdk).

Comment: And also remember to adds _BBCLASSEXTEND = "nativesdk"_ to _liblog4cxx10_ recipe.

Comment: I tried to add nativesdk in the lib recipe. There is an error because the lib depends on apr and "nativesdk-apr" do not exist...

Comment: native does not make sense, if you want the logging library in your cross-compilation target. I am not 100% sure, but i guess you need to install those libraries into your image as well.

Comment: for workaround , add those libs to your-extracted-SDK/cortex-a--/usr/lib/" then tou can compile

Comment: also add header files to "sdk/cortex-a--usr/include/" dir